# Django foreignkey issue in html

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Why i cant display the teacher name in my html? it is clearly that in my models StudentsEnrolledSubject i have foreignkey that connects in my another model SubjectSectionTeacher, and i just want to display the name of the teacher in my html, did i miss something? or i have query wrong?

**i have this code in my html**

```
{% for student in studentenrolledsubject %}
    <tr class="tr2">
        <td class="td" ><input type="text" name="students" value="{{student.id}}" id="student" hidden>{{student.Students_Enrollment_Records}}</td>
        <td class="td" ><input type="text" name="students" value="{{student.id}}" id="student" hidden>{{student.Subject_Section_Teacher__Employee_Users}}</td>
        <td data-id='row' id="ans"><input type='number' class='averages' step="any" name="average" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
{%endfor%}
```

**this is my views.py**

```
studentenrolledsubject= StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.filter(Subject_Section_Teacher__in = teacher.values_list('id')).distinct().order_by('id')
```

**this is my models.py**

```
class StudentsEnrolledSubject(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Subject_Section_Teacher = models.ForeignKey(SubjectSectionTeacher, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)


class SubjectSectionTeacher(models.Model):
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    Courses= models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Sections= models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Subjects= models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Employee_Users= models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `.` instead of `__`. You need `__` only in queryset to specify related objects attribute. In other cases use `.`:

```
<td class="td" ><input type="text" name="students" value="{{student.id}}" id="student" hidden>{{student.Subject_Section_Teacher.Employee_Users}}</td>
```